# Rescue, but still log error for Sentry/New Relic notification/logging

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, newrelic, sentry

Want to log an error that I can use with a Sentry/New Relic, etc. when an error is raised, but I rescue it.  Currently I use Sentry and it emails me all raised errors so I can fix them. However, when I rescue the error, no error gets raised, hence no idea anything is wrong.

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

  validates :name, :phone, :message, presence: true
  validates :email, format: {with: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i}

  def deliver
    if valid?
      begin
        return ContactUsMailer.contact(self).deliver
      rescue StandardError
        errors.add(:base, I18n.t("messages.unprocessed"))
        # Want to log an error that I can use with a Sentry/New Relic, etc.
        # Currently I use Sentry and it emails me all raised errors to I can fix them.
        false
      end
    end

    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the `sentry-raven` gem setup, you can also call

```
Raven.capture_exception(e)
```

For your example that should be

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

  validates :name, :phone, :message, presence: true
  validates :email, format: {with: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i}

  def deliver
    if valid?
      begin
        return ContactUsMailer.contact(self).deliver
      rescue StandardError => e
        Raven.capture_exception(e)
        errors.add(:base, I18n.t("messages.unprocessed"))
        # Want to log an error that I can use with a Sentry/New Relic, etc.
        # Currently I use Sentry and it emails me all raised errors to I can fix them.
        false
      end
    end

    false
  end
end
```

to ensure that the issue is still reported to sentry.

If your goal is to just report any text, the answer would be

```
Raven.capture_message("your text")
```

Also see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/usage/#reporting-messages

Answer (score 2):

You can just [manually log](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/#verify) the error to Sentry:

```
begin
  return ContactUsMailer.contact(self).deliver
rescue StandardError => exception
  errors.add(:base, I18n.t("messages.unprocessed"))
  Raven.capture_exception(exception)
  false
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to capture error with Raven? or just exceptions?

Comment: I am not sure if you understand your question? You do not need an exception when you want to log information to Raven. You can for example just send a string or a hash. But when the `ContractUsMailer` might raise exceptions then rescuing from that exception is the only way to avoid showing a `500 server error` to the user.

Comment: Agreeing with @spickermann on this case regarding exceptions.
The answer to your specific question would have been `capture_message`

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/usage/#reporting-messages